# Python "Pymoo" optimization package installation fail

Tags: python, optimization, pip, package

I'm trying to install the "pymoo" package in order to work on multi-objective optimization and when trying to install with the pip command: `pip install pymoo` I'm getting the retrying warnings:

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pymoo/`

`WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/pymoo/`

And so on.. until the count runs out and I get the following error messages:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pymoo`

`ERROR: No matching distribution found for pymoo`

I've tried installing by getting the code from GitHub and installing with `pip install .` , but it gives me the same error messages.

Is there anything I'm missing in the installation process?

Comment: check you internet connection, if you are installing it in work laptop/system then check the firewall also check the pytho version

Comment: python version 3.7.9 and i've disabled my firewall and still fails.

Comment: check your network or try in new shell

Comment: I did. Still same error. By the way - it shows also if I try ```pip install numpy``` for example.